# Resizing image within flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a pay layout which works how I want to when using the `.slides` element has a background colour and height, it flexes as expected, however when I switch to filling it with an image this behaviour breaks as the images won't resize and I can't get my head around how to make them resize.

The idea is the left column of text remains fixed size, and the right column flexes up and down, eventually snapping under the left column at small sizes.

The reason for using an `<img>` and not a background image is because there is a image slide show that I want to put in here.

Can anyone help fix this issue?

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.text {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 15em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.images {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-width: 15em;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.caption {
  margin-top: .25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="#">Title</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    <p>Something about this project is really interesting.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="images">
    <div class="slides">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x800">
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <p>Text about this project</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `The reason for using an <img> and not a background image is because there is a image slide show that I want to put in here.`. You could always set `style="background-image: url(...)` in your HTML rather than an IMG tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this ?

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
}

.text {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 15em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.images {
  flex:1 0 15em;
  min-width: 15em;
  max-width:800px;
}

.slides {
  display:flex;
}

.caption {
  margin-top: .25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="#">Title</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    <p>Something about this project is really interesting.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="images">
    <div class="slides">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x800" />
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <p>Text about this project</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope that doesn't seem to work, it doesn't rescale the image.

Comment: @unknowndomain It is resizing the image but to the 100% width of the container just try to resize the browser on full page.

Comment: When I click Run code snippet, the image doesn't scale at all.

Comment: @unknowndomain That is because I've kept your structure of flex-wrap and image size fixed to its maximum dimension. It has been scaled width wise. I'm not sure what else are you asking for? http://prntscr.com/hn6ffj

Comment: Ah sorry for the confusion, what I would like is for the image to have a minimum (15em) and maximum (800px) size, and that when you are on a wide screen it would side side-by-side up to that maximum, and as you scale down the image you'd see the white space eaten up, then the image scale down until it reaches the minimum size of 15em and snaps to the row beneath.

Comment: @unknowndomain Updated, do you mean this? Try to view it at full screen and resize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161234/discussion-between-unknowndomain-and-highdef).

Answer (score 2):

*Changes made:*

- Enabled responsiveness for `img` elements
- Commented out the `flex-wrap: wrap`
- Set `@media` queries to define when the wrapping inside the `.container` div takes place

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  display: block; /* removes bottom margin/whitespace */
  max-width: 100%; /* horizontally responsive */
  max-height: 100vh; /* vertically responsive */
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  /*flex-wrap: wrap;*/
}

.text {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 15em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.images {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-width: 15em;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.caption {
  margin-top: .25em;
}

@media (max-width: 33em) { /* 2 x 15em (.text & .images) + 2em  (left & right margin of the body element) + 1em (.text margin-right)  */
  .container {flex-wrap: wrap}
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="#">Title</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    <p>Something about this project is really interesting.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="images">
    <div class="slides">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x800">
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
      <p>Text about this project</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```